# Can an XML sitemap have Drupal permalink URLs instead of alias URLs?

Tags: xml-sitemap, drupal

While the following question is totally general and theoretical, it is based on a more particular case regarding the current development state of the simple_sitmeap module developed for Drupal 8 and aimed to replace the xml_sitemap module for Drupal 7. [Please read the current discussion in Drupal.org (starting from comment #3)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2772543) and then read here below.

Do you think it is dangerous or problematic to send to Google an XML sitemap that contains only (or mostly), permalinks (instead of aliases)?

In Drupal, [permalinks](https://www.drupal.org/project/permalink) look like this.  They are also known as "short links".   They are used when there is no alias for the page that would create a friendlier looking URL.

`http://www.example.com/page/123`

An [alias URL](https://www.drupal.org/node/120631) typically looks like this:

`http://www.example.com/page/page-name`

The user can manually assign an alias for the page, or install the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module that generates alias URLs based on the page title.  While an alias link might change if the page title changes, the permalink will not.

- If an alias URL exists, it would be desirable to have that friendly URL indexed.  If Google indexes the permalink instead, that would be problematic.
- It would be nice if Google uses the permalinks to discover and index the alias URLs.

AFAIK, Google and any other major SE like Bing, always crawls a page and get its alias; I am sure 99% that it will happen this time and the SERP will display aliases, but I can't say for sure given the fact I never sent an XML sitemap that includes permalinks.

### Comments update:

1. Closetnoc, I really don't want to do this; It's just that Drupal 8 is very new and the only xml_sitemap module available for it do it because of technical problem that the maintainer didn't have time to solve yet, and for now its the only option.
2. Stephen, I mean that what might appear in the SERP, are permalinks instead of aliases (it's unlikely in about 99% but I can't say for 100% as I never sent a sitemap with permalinks).
3. I can't say if its a redirect in the classic sense of 301's as I know Drupal just does "Aliasing" for each node with an internal Drupal 8 mechanism available under Config > Search & Metadata > URL aliases. Here is an example of the page that lets you do that:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It does not make sense to me. Why confuse things? Especially for something so important?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google indexes the addresses as with permalink"?   Are you trying to say that you don't want Google to index the content with the permalink URL?

Comment: Do your permalinks redirect?   Do they show the same page as on the other URL?   Which do you link to on your site?

Comment: Updated according to comments.

Comment: Here is another point of view. Sitemaps are largely unnecessary. They are only necessary for extremely large sites or where a search cannot crawl the entire site such as login or paywalls. If you have links to all of your pages and search engines can effectively crawl your site, then a sitemap is a waste. Cheers!!

Comment: I've edited the question after investigating how Drupal works a bit more.  I've added links to the relevant Drupal documentation as well as clarified some of your points.

Answer (score 2):

the question and the answer are pretty obvious - there is nothing tricky or ambiguous. Google has some clear sitemap guidelines meaning, that sitemap should contain:

- only urls answering with result code 200 OK,
- only urls which are allowed to be indexed,
- **only urls, which are canonical** - and this is probably not your case regarding permalinks

Comment: The last point is the most important one.

Comment: Why wouldn't a permalink be canonical?   I'm not very familiar with Drupal, but in WordPress the permalink URL is a page with just a single post on it, as opposed to a category page that may have the full text of several posts.  I don't think there is an "non permanent" URL for a single post.   Creating such a thing wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: There's no such thing as "non permament" URL for single post in wordpress. It doesn't make sense. What would that mean? I link you one thing, you click on another, and yet you are on the thing I've sent you? That's no-no.

Comment: After looking into to how drupal works I found that permalinks are **NOT** canonical.    For example, the canonical URL is https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto drupal also serves the same content (no redirects) on https://www.drupal.org/node/17345.    It has a canonical meta tag that points to the friendly URL.

Comment: Stephen, do you find that way in which Drupal works on this matter as problematic?

Comment: Anytime a CMS duplicates pages on different URLs it can be potentially problematic.   If my site were on Drupal, I would like to have the short links redirect rather than serve the page.   It sounds like I'd want the "Global Redirect" module. Using the canonical tag on those pages mitigates the problem for the major search engines.

Comment: When the URL of a page changes, the old URL should redirect to the new URL.  It sounds like you have to install an additional module to get that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll give it a shot.

First, to give a definition of sitemap:

> A site map (or sitemap) is a list of pages of a web site accessible to
>   crawlers or users. It can be either a document in any form used as a
>   planning tool for Web design, or a Web page that lists the pages on a
>   website, typically organized in hierarchical fashion.

In theory (and if sitemaps are what they are used to be)

It's not dangerous / problematic to send sitemap that has `www.example.com/page/123` instead of `www.example.com/page/page-name`. You can do whatever you like. But common sense will tell you to go with second option, because `/page/123` doesn't mean anything. `Page/page-name` means something.

Why? Well, let's get another definition:

> A Web crawler is an Internet bot which systematically browses the
>   World Wide Web, typically for the purpose of Web indexing (web
>   spidering). Web search engines and some other sites use Web crawling
>   or spidering software to update their web content or indexes of others
>   sites' web content.

So, you've noticed that it's content here that is important. It's on you how you'll build your link. I generally go by logic, but in this particular case, I'd be focused on content that is on my page instead of my link.

It's just link building here.

And please... I just want you to ask you a question regarding your question, and please elaborate in comment. Beacuse, I didn't understand that part.

> I never sent a sitemap with permalinks

Are you sure about this statement?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. About the last part: AFAICR, it was always aliases.

Comment: you should know that permalinks do not change, and that aliases do.

Comment: and also, it's still not problematic for google, sometimes it's good. Rly.

Comment: I know that permalinks (usually) don't change and that aliases are (more occasionally) do. I meant to say that AFAICR, when I sent sitemaps in history ---> It was always with alaises and not permalinks...

Comment: well, I think that my and evgeniy's combination of answers will give you a better picture.